# Are there any other ways of starting MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose, backend

I've been learning MongoDB and Mongoose for quite some time now, but I don't know if there are any other (easier/quicker) ways of starting MongoDB. The way I start it now is I open PowerShell (I'm on Windows) and type out or paste this command:

```
C:/Users/Administrator/mongodb/bin/mongod.exe --dbpath=C:/Users/Administrator/mongodb-data
```

It gets a little bit boring to always paste that command every time. I did google it, but didn't find any straight answers.

Comment: You can install it as a service `mongod.exe --install --config <your configuration file>`. Or have a look at https://github.com/Wernfried/mongoDB-oneclick

Answer (score 0):

Use a docker image. It is cleaner and quicker.